# Modulus Operation on powers of a number by hand

Tags: modular-arithmetic

It is fairly straightforward to perform a modulus operation on small numbers by hand, but is there an easy way to find the modulus of larger numbers based on the smaller roots? For example:

180 mod 13 is 11. Is there an easy way to find, by hand, the following:

- 180^2 mod 13
- 180^4 mod 13
- 180^8 mod 13
- 180^12 mod 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, via successive squaring:

- $180^2 \equiv 11^2 \equiv 121 \equiv -9 \equiv 4 \pmod{13}$
- $180^4 = (180^2)^2 \equiv 4^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{13}$
- $180^8 = (180^4)^2 \equiv \cdots$

and so on. In this manner, any exponent which is a power of $2$ can be done. Now for other exponents, write as a sum of powers of $2$ - for example, $12 = 8 + 4$.